# CanvasKit Error: Uncaught RuntimeError: index out of bounds

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvaskit

I'm making a animation engine, and it is being replaced and refactored with Canvaskit, I tried to use CanvasKit to load an animation, this is my code:

```js
import { config } from "@newcar/utils";
import type { Canvas, CanvasKit, Paint, Surface } from "canvaskit-wasm";
import CanvasKitInit from "canvaskit-wasm";
import mitt from "mitt";

import type { Scene } from "./scene";

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions
export type CarHookEventMap = {
  "before-frame-update": Car;
  "frame-updated": Car;
};

export class Car {
  private _playing!: boolean;
  private lastUpdateTime!: number;
  // readonly context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  readonly canvasKitLoaded = CanvasKitInit({
    locateFile(_file) {
      return config.canvaskitWasmFile;
    },
  });

  canvaskit: CanvasKit;
  paint: Paint;
  surface: Surface;
  events: {
    "ready-to-play": (() => any)[];
  } = {
    "ready-to-play": [],
  };

  readonly hook = mitt<CarHookEventMap>();

  constructor(public element: HTMLCanvasElement, public scene: Scene) {
    this.playing = false;
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    // this.context = this.element.getContext("2d")!;
    this.canvasKitLoaded.then((canvaskit) => {
      this.canvaskit = canvaskit;
      this.surface = canvaskit.MakeWebGLCanvasSurface(this.element);
      this.paint = new canvaskit.Paint();
      for (const callback of this.events["ready-to-play"]) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }

  static update(car: Car): void {
    car.hook.emit("before-frame-update", car);

    let elapsed: number;
    switch (config.timing) {
      case "frame": {
        elapsed = 1;
        break;
      }
      case "second": {
        const currentTimestamp = performance.now();
        const intervalTime = (currentTimestamp - car.lastUpdateTime) / 1000;
        car.lastUpdateTime = currentTimestamp;
        elapsed = intervalTime;
        break;
      }
    }
    car.scene.elapsed += elapsed;
    // car.context.clearRect(0, 0, car.element.width, car.element.height);

    for (const update of car.scene.updates) {
      update(car.scene.elapsed);
    }
    (function f(objects: typeof car.scene.objects) {
      for (const object of objects) {
        object.beforeUpdate(car);
        for (const animation of object.animations) {
          if (animation.elapsed <= animation.duration) {
            animation.elapsed += elapsed;
            animation.animate(
              object,
              animation.elapsed / animation.duration,
              animation.by,
              animation.params ?? {},
            );
          }
        }
        f(object.children);
        object.updated(car);
      }
    })(car.scene.objects);

    try {
      car.surface.drawOnce((canvas: Canvas) => { // The problem is start from this column.
        canvas.clear(car.canvaskit.BLACK);
        for (const object of car.scene.objects) {
          object.update(car.paint, canvas, car.canvaskit);
          object.updated(car);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {}
    car.hook.emit("frame-updated", car);

    if (car.playing) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => Car.update(car));
    }
  }

  play(at?: number): this {
    this.playing = true;
    if (typeof at !== "undefined") {
      this.scene.elapsed = at;
    }

    return this;
  }

  stop(at?: number): this {
    this.playing = false;
    if (typeof at !== "undefined") {
      this.scene.elapsed = at;
    }

    return this;
  }

  on(event: "ready-to-play", callback: () => any): this {
    switch (event) {
      case "ready-to-play": {
        this.events[event].push(callback);
        break;
      }
    }

    return this;
  }

  get playing(): boolean {
    return this._playing;
  }

  set playing(playing: boolean) {
    this._playing = playing;
    if (playing) {
      this.lastUpdateTime = performance.now();
      requestAnimationFrame(() => Car.update(this));
    }
  }
}
```

It erred:  Uncaught RuntimeError: index out of bounds

and the browser tips is refering to `canvaskit-wasm.js:3787` and the problem seems to be at 92th row, in `car.surface.drawOnce` (I have signed it in codes, and you can find it in https://github.com/Bug-Duck/newcar/blob/093b14704951d2986ecfe5313f9ae3bec6874f88/packages/core/src/car.ts

I hope the animation could be ran directly.